# Doesn't EF Power Tools CTP1 work with customized connectionstring?

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

**[Environment]**

- Windows 7 Ultra
- VS 2010 Ultra
- Entity Framework 4.2
- Entity Framework Power Tool CTP1

**[Details]:**

I'm doing some exercises about EF Code-First. During doing it with local server of SQL Sever 2008 Express, the EF Power Tool can display the entity data model diagram. it works well.

After I define a connectionstring in app.config to connect a LAN server of SQL Server 2008, view the entity data model again. The EF Power Tool shows me a dialog of error HResult 0x000xxxx. By running the application, it rebuilds the tables in database as I expect.

I found a comment in the page of downloading EF Power Tool CTP1. The Devart team gets the problem like me.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d?SRC=VSIDE

**[Question]:**

1. Is any tool like the EF Power Tool to create data model diagram with POCOs and DbContext?
2. How to do to fix the problem above?

THX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Unlike EF Power Tool, Devart Entity Developer allows you to create data model diagram with POCOs and DbContext at design time initially. Please take a look at [this](http://www.devart.com/blogs/dotconnect/index.php/entity-developer-ef-code-first-dbcontext-template.html) article.
2. Since there is the problem with usage of existing DbContext with connection string from the *.config file, you can be interested in generating Code-First fluent mapping by Devart Entity Developer.
   However, if you are going to use EF Power Tool, please take a look at [this](http://www.devart.com/blogs/dotconnect/index.php/using-entity-framework-power-tools-ctp1-with-oracle-mysql-postgresql-and-sqlite.html) article.

Devart Team

Comment: I tried to set the DefaultConnectionFactory in the main(), but didn't place it into the context constructor. The problem is so awful.   Thanks.